# Weird spaces in text after decoded in base64

Tags: text, utf-8, base64, decode, whitespace

To give context, every receipt must have QR code that contain (The name of store, VAT number, Date and time, total price, VAT price) when you read that QR code it give a base64 text that have the previous information but it aslo have that weird spaces in between that i don't understand and some how it required by the official apps that read the QR code

Base64 example text:

```
AR5Vbml2ZXJzYWwgQ29sZCBTdG9yZSBUcmRnLiBDby4CDzMwMDU2Mjg2MjQxMDAwMwMTMjAyMy0wNC0yMiAxODoyNzoxNQQFMjUuODgFBDMuMzg=
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the data the two bytes before each string are a string number (1-5 in the data), and the length of the following string.

Here's Python code to extract the data:

```py
import base64

s = 'AR5Vbml2ZXJzYWwgQ29sZCBTdG9yZSBUcmRnLiBDby4CDzMwMDU2Mjg2MjQxMDAwMwMTMjAyMy0wNC0yMiAxODoyNzoxNQQFMjUuODgFBDMuMzg='
data = base64.b64decode(s)
while data:
    num = data[0]
    size = data[1]
    string = data[2:2+size].decode('ascii')  # assume data is ASCII-encoded
    print(f'{num=} {size=} {string=}')
    data = data[size+2:]  # remove num/size/string from the data
```

Output:

```
num=1 size=30 string='Universal Cold Store Trdg. Co.'
num=2 size=15 string='300562862410003'
num=3 size=19 string='2023-04-22 18:27:15'
num=4 size=5 string='25.88'
num=5 size=4 string='3.38'
```

Comment: can you please add more details about "STRING NUMBER", and if I want to create a new base64 with it how?

Comment: I'm just looking at the data.  The first byte is a 1, the next byte is a size, then "size" bytes of a string.  Then then next byte is a number (2), a size, and data, etc.  You haven't mentioned any apps or even a language.  There may be a formal specification for this somewhere.

Comment: I think it's a Unicode escape sequence: \u0019Universe Cold Store Trdg. Co.. \u003030562862410003\u0013\u0203-04-22 18:27:15\u0025.88\u0003.38

Comment: It's not.  It's clearly a number scheme and a string size.  Perhaps the first byte is a string ID.  #1 is a store name, #2 is the VAT number, #3 is the timestamp, etc.  Then maybe you can write them in a different order and identify by ID.  The 2nd byte exactly matches each string length.

Comment: Yep it's a scheme after looking for the guideline document: https://zatca.gov.sa/en/E-Invoicing/Introduction/Guidelines/Documents/E-invoicing-Detailed-Technical-Guideline.pdf